# What happens after being put in the penalty box two (or more) times?

Tags: support, suspensions

I've been thrown in the penalty box because I allegedly made rude comments and I had to cool down. What happens if one is thrown in the box for a second (or third, fourth...) time? Will he/she (or I) get extra punishment on top?
Is there a limit on the number of times you can be put in there?
Notice I'm not asking how the suspension time is determined. I explicitly ask what will happen after being suspended several times. Do the times you are suspended simply are added up until a limit is reached to be banned?

Comment: What is missing from what is in the linked duplicate? "There is no permanent suspension, one year is the maximum generally used." "The guidelines from SE on suspension lengths are 7 days for the first offense..."

Comment: Additionally, please do not repost questions that have been closed as a duplicate. Instead edit the question, or explain in comments why you believe it is not a duplicate.